# How to see free space of permanently mounted drive (Ubuntu 22.04)

Tags: mount, 22.04, ssd, nas

I'm building from scratch a NAS with one 240 Gb NVME, to which I already added an other internal SSD of 250 Gb.
Thing is, as I mounted it to /ssd as specified in the /etc/fstab, I can't seem to find the free space of that SSD anymore. In fact, even though I can create files in /ssd and it seems to work properly, Ubuntu only says that I have 240 Gbs of total space. What did I do wrong?
Thanks :)

Comment: What does `lsblk` say? Does it show separate devices? I take it the SSD is properly mounted and the filesystem is recognized.

Answer (score 1):

Go to a command line and use:

```
df -h
```

*OR*

```
lsblk -e 7 -f
```

It's possible with btrfs, zfs, or xfs filesystems Ubuntu gui tools will not read them correctly at all.

Comment: Why do they need to exclude devices? What exactly does "-e 7" do, don't you need details of their specific devices to know what digit to use there?

Comment: @pbhj Those exclude all the snap loop back devices which never have been anything but 7 on any system I've used.